# How do I obtain the SKSpriteNode of an item created through SpriteKit Editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have created a fairly simple (at this point, experimental) "game" in XCode using SpriteKit (with Objective-C).

I know how to manually create a SKSpriteNode object and add it to the SKScene - but I am kind of trying to do the opposite - where I created the sprite inside the XCode SceneKit GUI itself (and gave it a name), now I want to *retreive* it in my code.

In prior experience with XCode, you would do this by declaring a @property UIOutlet [etc] and then connecting it as a referencing outlet inside the IB/Storyboard UI - but I can't find any similar way to do that inside the SpriteKit UI.

I can create a property (as an SKSpriteNode), and name it the same as my SpriteKit object - and it shows up under the SKScene (in the debugger), but is "nil" - i.e. is not "associated" with the object I created in the XCode SpriteKit UI.

Am I missing something - or doing this completely wrong? :-O

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you set the name property of a node in the Sprite Kit Editor, you can access the node, in Swift, by

```
if let node = self.childNodeWithName("NodeName") as? SKSpriteNode {
    // Set up your sprite here
}
```

or

```
SKSpriteNode *node = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"NodeName"];
```

in Obj-C.

Comment: Note: This mechanism only works if the node is a direct child of the scene. You'll need to manually walk the node tree with multiple calls if it is more complex.

Comment: @bshirley SpriteKit will search recursively through the node tree if you add "//" to the front of the name (e.g., "//NodeName").

Comment: @0x141E have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525232/replacing-calayer-and-cabasicanimation-with-skscene-and-skactions